# Out of box Apache install on Ubuntu 16.04 very slow

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

- A new C5.4xLarge (16 Cores, 32 GB RAM) EC2 instance has been created with the Ubuntu Server 16.04 AMI.
- Server is assigned an elastic IP and a security group opening port 80 is applied.
- Server is updated with `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`
- Oracle Java 9 is installed on the server using
  oracle-java-9-installer from the linuxuprising/java PPA.
- LXDE and XRDP are installed and started.
- Apache2 is installed `apt-get install apache2`

When accessing the server's public IP (`http://18.xxx.xxx.xxx`) from a browser, it takes 10 to 15 seconds for index.html to load, every time. After pushing another basic website into a subfolder of /var/www/html, it too takes a super long time to open and process any pages.

**Does anyone have any ideas why a basically vanilla server with a default installation of Apache is failing to serve even the default Apache page in a timely fashion?**

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by giving the server a fully qualified domain name and creating a DNS entry for it. Then the websites were accessed using the FQDN rather than the IP address and the problem went away.